# Accessing Controller same name but different namespace in mvc 3.0

Tags: model-view-controller

I want to call a HomeController that is in under the Controller/Admin but this is not calling and generating the error's because there is another HomeController in /Controller.
I resolved the error by adding below code

```
   routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                new string[] { "MyProject.Web.Controllers" }
```

but i am able to access the admin/homecontroller.

Please suggest me how can i do it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the other namespace to the string array of namespaces

```
new string[] { "MyProject.Web.Controllers", "MyProject.Web.Controllers.Admin" }
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, this helped me with multiple `MVC4 apps` in a partitioned solutions